# In Wordpress i have use 2 different theme but when i switch one theme to another theme Widgets on page plugin goes to inactive

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using two different theme for website and for desktop and for mobile.and i am using Widget on page plugin for call widget in Wordpress post and pages. but when i switch on theme to another theme Widgets on page plugin goes to inactive Widgets part. And that widget area display empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**thats because you are using widgets which are theme specific(which comes with a theme)**